# Updating the alignment box in Visio

Tags: ms-office, visio

I have created a master shape which is a small rectangle. I used the code to extract the coordinates from a *.CSV file, made the master shape to be dropped on the page and apply those coordinated to it. As it turns out that the final shape is much larger than the initial master shape I created. My problem is the alignment box that surrounds the shape, for resize and rotation, is still the same small size as it was in the original shape. Is it possible to make the alignment box reset to the new shape?

Here is an image. The gray area is the new shape. The wire like rectangle is the alignment box of master shape. The top image shows the gray area as the new shape and the tiny wire like alignment box in the lower left corner of the shape. This is how it comes out.

What I want is shown in the second image. The alignment box should cover the entire shape and not just the tiny lower left corner.
How do I make the alignment box to cover the entire shape?

[image: Image 1 shows the gray area as the new shape and the tiny wire like alignment box in the lower left corner of the shape. This is how it comes out.]

[image: Image 2 shows how it should be. The alignment box should cover the entire shape and not just the tiny lower left corner.]

How do I get this to work? Any thoughts?

As always, any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

-Miki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution to this question via Visioguy forum and I am posting the answer here so that incase someone might end up here trying to find the same thing.

In Visio, there is a function called, "Update Alignment Box". I used that function and added a line to my code to do it programmatically.
Here is the line:

```
activewindow.selection.updatealignmentbox
```

-Miki